# Custom 404 page sends 200 status code

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

404 error page's `200 OK` header error:

> Server Response:
>   http://www.example.com/err404.html HTTP
>   Status Code: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

And it should give 404, my client says.

Comment: This is called a soft 404, whereas a hard ('proper') 404 actually returns 400 Not Found

Answer (score 8):

I guess that you use [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) with an absolute URL like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/err404.html
```

In that case the server responds with a 302 redirect with *http://example.com/err404.html* as the location. If that URL is then requested, your server is sending the 200 status code as you experienced.

Try just an absolute URL path instead:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /err404.html
```

Comment: yes, good guess you have :) i had http://www.blabla.com/err404.html url. i just edited as you said, how can i control if it is fine now? where can i see this 200OK error msg? in firebug? or anything else? thanks

Comment: +1 for the guess. @artmania: just request an non-existing URL and check response headers.

Comment: I believe artmania is asking *how* to "check response headers". The answer: yes, Firebug can do that, specifically in the Net view, as seen in this screenshot: http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/renso/Firebug/FirebugNetworkAllSample(1).png

Comment: i tried an absolute url path, and tested with web-sniffer.net. it still looks 200 OK ,here is screenshot http://files.droplr.com/files/15306373/9PYdc.View%20HTTP%20Request%20and%20Response%20Header.jpg :(

Comment: @artmania: And what resource did you request? An existing or a non-existing?

Answer (score 4):

You will get status 200 if the error page was the **actual** request (i.e. the error page is requested directly by browser address bar, a bookmark, a *redirect* in PHP, etc). You will get status 404 if the error page was returned by the webserver itself when there's actually means of invalid request, or when it is dynamically included by PHP along with `header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");`. In Apache HTTP server the locations for custom error pages are configureable somewhere in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: thanks for detailed info. what is so bad about this? it is redirecting to 404 anyway.. i dont get the point.

Comment: You should not redirect. It will result in a 200. I think your major problem is that you don't understand how HTTP works.